# Burninate [toggle]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

From the wiki:

> To toggle a boolean variable is to switch it to it's opposite state. If it is on, switch it off; if it is off, switch it on. In a desktop or web user interface, a toggle may be clickable switch or button that alternates the state of something in the application.

Looking at the questions tagged with this, I see questions about jQuery, Android, HTML5, WPF, XAML, etc.

You can't exactly be an expert in toggling things so I propose removing this tag.

There are 2,708 questions tagged with [toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggle). Examples:

- [Toggle visibility of divs based on multiple checkboxes using AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664037/toggle-visibility-of-divs-based-on-multiple-checkboxes-using-and-operator)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628189/toggle-in-listview-wont-remain-state-and-other-positions-get-pressed
- [how to disable sound in my game app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027302/how-to-disable-sound-in-my-game-app)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635864/jquery-toggle-function-on-dynamic-id

Finally, this tag only has **4** followers.

Comment: I answer questions in the jQuery and HTML5 section quite often, I would say personally that I've seen useful questions about toggling. You can be an expect and state switching, which involve toggling between two states. So I don't think this tag is so useless that it should be removed.

Comment: The tags about toggling boolean should be [tag:boolean], not [tag:toggle]

Comment: I would like to see tags be language technology specific and not about a reference to what you want your code to do. I think SO needs to revisit what tags should actually be for.